# Where did my system partition go after cloning from my previous hard drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, ssd, disk-management

I recently bought a 250GB Samsung 850 Pro SSD for my laptop, and used [AOMEI Partition Assistant](http://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-software.html) to clone my previous hard drive. One completed, I physically replaced swapped out the two drives, booted up and everything worked fine (expect much faster of course!).

However, upon opening up a "This PC" window, I discovered that there was only the C: partition, as you can see here.

[image: What my "This PC" screen looks like.]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

Here is what my "Disk Management" screen looks like:

[image]

Now I don't really mind that they're gone, since it was just Recovery and HP_Tools, but I'm a bit worried about SYSTEM.

**I would like to know:**

1. Are they actually there and just hidden? If so how do I find them?
2. Is there a reduction in features/performance? Because I read [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/192772/what-is-the-system-reserved-partition-and-can-you-delete-it/) that without the SYSTEM partition the computer can't even boot.
3. Did I even need them anyway?
4. Did AOMEI Partition Assistant combine all of the data of the other partitions into the one 600MB NTFS partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All the available partitions are visible within Disk Management. It's possible the partition you're thinking of is the first one which doesn't have a volume label or a drive letter. As it's an NTFS partition, you can right click this and click `Change Drive Letter and Paths`, followed by `Add` and give it a drive letter so you can see the contents.
2. Your computer has booted, so you have nothing to worry about. It depends on how your machine boots - if it uses an MBR to boot you don't need any special partitions. EFI typically has a special EFI partition to store bootloader entries, usually the first partition of the disk.
3. No, however you may have lost the HP recovery data, and possibly any diagnostic utilities you may get on boot. It won't affect your day-to-day running.
4. This is unlikely, unless you told it to it should be keeping partitions exactly as they were. Unfortunately without seeing the process you did, it's hard to say exactly what has been cloned, it's possible one of the partitions just wasn't cloned, and the other is there but without a drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your last picture of Disk Management. Your SYSTEM partition and all other partitions exist within the C:\ volume. I think you are good to go.

Use DISKPART to get a list of all partitions, volumes.

Open up a Command-Line Window:

```
DISKPART
```

Then when DISKPART launches do the following:

```
List disk
```

Then

```
List partition
```

Then

```
List volume
```

Then

```
List vdisk
```

You should be able to get all of your information through DISKPART.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 partitions but in this PC you see only partitions that have a drive letter. The other partition has no drive letter but that one contains your bootmgr. That is your current system partition.